# I want to print a double sided BOOK not booklet that is 200 pages long

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, book

My book is 200pages long.I need to print double sided but I want it bound properly so needs to be in order for guillotine and stacking.My paper size is A4 but the book is A5 sideways on the A4 paper and double sided.I did this twice before for books but am now 65 and the settings are eluding me to the point of distraction.Any help would be appreciated. I have spent 3 days on this and loads of paper already...Perhaps I need to change my name

Comment: With a reader spread document choose File > Print Booklet...

Comment: This is the kind of question which might be a good fit for the proposed Graphic Design Software Support stack. Please see the proposal and follow it if you think it might be useful. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86994/graphic-design-software-support/

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted. The question is related to imposing signatures and is something that mainly only specialists know how to do. Seems a perfect question and AFAIK, is not handled by the standard-issue software. Perhaps an overview of how to do it manually (rather than software recommendations) would be useful. I am not qualified.

Comment: how are you binding the book and what software are you using ?

Comment: I think you need to explain what you see as the difference between a "book" and a "booklet". From a print perspective, there's little difference except maybe creep. Most of the difference between those two would be seen in the binding.

Answer (score 2):

ON *nix systems there is a command called [`psbook` (see instructions here)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCoQFjAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpgeeltex.googlecode.com%2Ffiles%2FMaking%2520booklets%2520with%2520psbook%2520and%2520psnup.pdf&ei=7sdXVd2UMouisgG6yID4Cg&usg=AFQjCNF2dPwgRnj9yK7UrICnxiWQLCgygw&sig2=hgcreLu5QF8tEtMG3ZZ-2g&bvm=bv.93564037,d.bGg&cad=rja) and `psnup` so you can probably find it for osX. For windows you can get it with cygwin. what you would do is call:

```
psbook -s16 print.ps out.ps
psnup -la4 -2 out.ps > out2up.ps
```

This will make pages with 16 page long signatures or 4 paper groups. You can change this by editing the `-s` flag.

It is also possible to do this with Acrobat scripting. But you can also use standalone tools like [bookbinder](http://www.quantumelephant.co.uk/bookbinder/bookbinder.html)or [pdfbook](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/pdfbook/) instead.

#### References

- [PSUtils](http://www.uibk.ac.at/th-physik/howto/psutils.html)